# Python thread suspended/stop without exception or error-throw

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-multithreading

I am doing web-scraping using python threads. Below is example code. I just mention 3 of them but actually their are 20 threads. In main time all threads run without error but after sometime one of thread suspended without any exception or error-throw.

How can I handle this exception ???

```
from threading import Thread
import threading
from time import sleep

# variables

f_price = 1000
l_price = 6000


def main(f_price, l_price):

    print(threading.currentThread().getName(), 'just Start the Job')
    
    for each_iteration in range(1,5):
        print('Hi I am', threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Price Lies Between is:', f_price, '-', l_price)
        print('\n')

        f_price = l_price
        l_price += 5000

    print(threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Finish the Job')


thread1 = Thread(target=main, args=(f_price, l_price)
thread2 = Thread(target=main, args=(f_price, l_price)
thread3 = Thread(target=main, args=(f_price, l_price)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()
thread3.join()
```

Comment: Btw do you know that you are not updating the global value of `l_price`? If your goal is to update that global value you have to use `global` keyword and some synchronisation to ensure right result. Recommend reading more about parallel programming in Python and GIL (Global interpreter lock) in general.

Comment: Otherwise this example looks without problems.

Comment: I don't see any evidence of an exception here. Please show your stack trace

Comment: @mikulatomas yes I know, global value for both variables are not updated. Each thread has his on value, which gone update on every iteration.......

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes you are right.